# Make Links in a Composite File (Overleaf)

Tags: hyperref, links

I want to insert bookmarks, or links to other pages of a "book" I'm writing. Since the book is rather long, I split it into multiple files, but linking doesn't seem to work.

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}
\hyperref[sec:hello]{text}
\newpage
\label{sec:hello}
\input{Hello} % another sub-document with stuff written on it
\end{document}
```

However, this link just brings a few lines down to the original link itself instead ofthe next page. How can I fix this?

Comment: You must add an anchor before the label, either with some sectioning command, or with \phantomsection.

Comment: Is there a way to do that *without* impacting the look on the compiled pdf?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Also, everything about anchors online are about `TikZ`. What is an anchor?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. It is independent of having text in several files or in only one file IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem but here is a start/guess.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{filecontents}{FileA.tex}
\section{Section A}
\label{sec:A}
Text
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{FileB.tex}
\section{Section B}
\label{sec:B}
Text
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\input{FileA.tex}
\input{FileB.tex}

Links to Section~\ref{sec:A} and Section~\ref{sec:B}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Close. However, I don't want to impact the looks of the compiled document. That is, I don't really want the `section` to be placed. But I can deal with that if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @CELLSecret I cannot reply properly right now, I am only on my phone. Please Google for phantomsection as recommended by Ulrike and/or ask a clearer question.

Comment: You can take my code as a starting point.

Comment: nvm I got it :)